# Is it possible to connect IBOutlet variable from storyboard with the class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class, object

I have created a class in the viewController with all the characteristics the button should have, my main question is how to connect this class to all the other buttons in the storyboard, is it possible to connect the IBOutlet variable with the class and that way create an object? For example, create one class of buttons in the calculator and merge all buttons with one class so that the characteristics will be the same and I won’t create the same characteristics for each button

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of UIButton, and in interface builder use that class after you drag a button on to the canvas. Any common customizations for that button style can be done in that class. See the attached image!

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but in my case it didn’t work unfortunately